# Error "headers already sent" in WAMP localhost

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I'm using WAMP. And I was wondering why I don't see **headers already sent** errors on my localhost. I tried using XAMPP but the errors are invisible as well.

As soon as I transfer the website to a live domain I can see the errors.

I tried changing the error_reporting in php.ini to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

I rebooted the WAMP server, but i still don't see the errors. Any ideas? Thanks!

### Edit

ob_flush is working, I placed it at the beginning and at the end of the document. It is well explained here [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

But I still would like to see the errors without having to test on a live server.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);`?

Answer (score 1):

Compare the 2 sites and look for this setting in the php.ini file being used by Apache.

*On Wamp, use the wampmanager menus to make sure you are viewing the correct php.ini.*

```
output_buffering = On
```

I would imaging that one site has it set `off` and the other has it set `on`